# How to diagnose uploads failing only on OS X clients

Tags: php, macos, file-upload, is-uploaded-file

We recently upgrade our server to PHP 5 and file uploads are now failing, but only from OS X clients (Safari 5, Firefox 3.6) although the same browser versions on Windows work fine.

The code is failing as `is_uploaded_file()` is returning false when using Mac client software.

Has anyone had this error before?

Any suggestions for how I might diagnose the cause of this problem?

Comment: First step: `print_r($_FILES);` and http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many MacOSX users are reporting this issue?  Just a small portion of your mac users, or all of them?  Do you have a Mac nearby to reproduce the problem?  I'd be surprised if a PHP file as common as is_uploaded_file is the problem.  I'd lean towards issues on the client side, or network issues.  You could check the log files (if you are using apache /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/httpd) for their upload connection information or possible errors

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem recently as well - only with safari though. I haven't had time to do a fix yet, but was going to look at what is suggested here:

safari upload woes - http://www.webmasterworld.com/macintosh_webmaster/3341383.htm

I agree that this is most not likely a php problem.